# React / Dropdown with multiple Components don't show child items

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a React beginer and i want to create a Dropdown with React so i do following code:

Modul dropdown.js

```
var React = require('react');

var DropdownItemWrapper = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        console.log("listItems.map")
        return React.createElement(
            'li',
            null,
            this.props.itemdata
        );
    }
});

var Dropdown = React.createClass({

    displayName:'Dropdown',

    render: function(){

        return React.createElement(
            "div",
            {className:this.props.className},
            React.createElement(
                'button',
                {className:'btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle', 'type':'button', 'data-toggle':'dropdown'},
                this.props.title,
                React.createElement(
                    'span',
                    {className:'caret'}
                )
            ),
            React.createElement(
                'ul',
                this.props.listWrapperAttr,
                this.props.listItems.map(function(result) {
                    React.createElement(DropdownItemWrapper, {itemdata:result});
                })
            )
        );
    }
});

module.exports = {
    create: React.createFactory(Dropdown),
    Dropdown: Dropdown
};
```

and then i catch it in the frontend:

```
var React = require('react');
var dropdown = require('../base/dropdown');
// DROPDOWN
React.render(dropdown.create({
    title: 'Auswahl Dropdown',
    className: 'dropdown',
    listWrapperAttr: {className:'dropdown-menu'},
    listItems:['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5']
}), document.getElementById('react-dropdown'));
```

but at the end there is no list items in the dropdown-menu, but there is no error message. DropdownItemWrapper don#T give anything back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning from your `.map` function which is why you're not seeing any items.

As to why you're not seeing an error is because anything that returns `null`, `undefined`, `false` or empty array React will just skip rendering for that output.

```
this.props.listItems.map(function(result) {
    return React.createElement(DropdownItemWrapper, {itemdata:result});
})
```

Comment: Shit, you are right, i forgot to return the map result, because i thought(!) i don't need to return something... i found the solution last night .. sorry for posting...